# Apache Drill ExtractHeader option causing load issues with Drill Explorer

Tags: csv, unhandled-exception, apache-drill

I'm trying to explore a CSV with Apache Drill 1.3.0 through Drill Explorer (1.2 64-bit). When the extractHeader setting set to true (`"extractHeader": true,`) in the storage configurations options (for dfs and s3a plugins) any attempt to load the csv (i.e. click on the file in the drill explorer) results in the unhandled exception error:

`Column 'columns' does not belong to table Table.`

What is the cause of this problem? Is there a fix or is it an unresolved bug?

I've tested it with other CSVs and I get the same problem. I realised it as extractHeader because I turned it off and the problem didn't occur. Full extract of the error is below.

If needed I can upload this original CSV, screenshots and drill storage config file.

```
************** Exception Text **************
System.ArgumentException: Column 'columns' does not belong to table Table.
   at System.Data.DataRow.GetDataColumn(String columnName)
   at DrillExplorer.DRExploreTablesDialog.RetrieveCSVMetadata(String schemaName, String path)
   at DrillExplorer.DRExploreTablesDialog.BrowseDfsNode(DRTreeNode dfsNode)
   at DrillExplorer.DRExploreTablesDialog.browseTreeView_AfterSelect(Object sender, TreeViewEventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Forms.TreeView.OnAfterSelect(TreeViewEventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Forms.TreeView.TvnSelected(NMTREEVIEW* nmtv)
   at System.Windows.Forms.TreeView.WmNotify(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.TreeView.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.Callback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)


************** Loaded Assemblies **************
mscorlib
    Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 4.6.127.1 built by: NETFXREL3STAGE
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.NET/Framework64/v4.0.30319/mscorlib.dll
----------------------------------------
DrillExplorer
    Assembly Version: 1.2.0.0
    Win32 Version: 1.2.0.0
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Program%20Files/MapR%20Drill%20ODBC%20Driver/lib/DrillExplorer.exe
----------------------------------------
System.Windows.Forms
    Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 4.6.79.0 built by: NETFXREL2
    CodeBase: file:///C:/WINDOWS/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Windows.Forms/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.Windows.Forms.dll
----------------------------------------
System
    Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 4.6.79.0 built by: NETFXREL2
    CodeBase: file:///C:/WINDOWS/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.dll
----------------------------------------
System.Drawing
    Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 4.6.93.0 built by: NETFXREL2STAGE
    CodeBase: file:///C:/WINDOWS/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Drawing/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a/System.Drawing.dll
----------------------------------------
System.Configuration
    Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 4.6.79.0 built by: NETFXREL2
    CodeBase: file:///C:/WINDOWS/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Configuration/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a/System.Configuration.dll
----------------------------------------
System.Core
    Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 4.6.79.0 built by: NETFXREL2
    CodeBase: file:///C:/WINDOWS/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Core/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.Core.dll
----------------------------------------
System.Xml
    Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 4.6.79.0 built by: NETFXREL2
    CodeBase: file:///C:/WINDOWS/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Xml/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.Xml.dll
----------------------------------------
System.Data
    Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 4.6.127.1 built by: NETFXREL3STAGE
    CodeBase: file:///C:/WINDOWS/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_64/System.Data/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.Data.dll
----------------------------------------
System.Transactions
    Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 4.6.79.0 built by: NETFXREL2
    CodeBase: file:///C:/WINDOWS/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_64/System.Transactions/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.Transactions.dll
----------------------------------------
System.EnterpriseServices
    Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 4.6.79.0 built by: NETFXREL2
    CodeBase: file:///C:/WINDOWS/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_64/System.EnterpriseServices/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a/System.EnterpriseServices.dll
----------------------------------------
System.Numerics
    Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 4.6.79.0 built by: NETFXREL2
    CodeBase: file:///C:/WINDOWS/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Numerics/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.Numerics.dll
----------------------------------------
```

Answer (score 1):

I tested a simple csv (test.csv):

```
name,age,salary
dev,23,10000
karthik,23,20000
amit,24,30000
```

"csv" part in my `dfs` plugin:

```
 "csv": {
      "type": "text",
      "extensions": [
        "csv"
      ],
      "extractHeader": true,
      "delimiter": ","
    },
```

> Note: Make sure `"skipFirstLine": true` should not be there.

Query:

```
select * from dfs.`/home/dev/sample-data/test.csv`;
```

Output:

```
+----------+------+---------+
|   name   | age  | salary  |
+----------+------+---------+
| dev      | 23   | 10000   |
| karthik  | 23   | 20000   |
| amit     | 24   | 30000   |
+----------+------+---------+
```

Comment: That's the odd thing - I can run the query from the command line without any issues (like you've done above). It's only when I use Drill Explorer to query the data does it throw up this error.

Comment: Then you can raise an issue regarding this.